# How can I improve this two-pass JavaScript data filter?

Tags: javascript, filter, underscore.js, lodash

My app gets a list of items, each with a state property that can have a value of "foo," "bar," "blah," etc.  Sometimes the list will have items that are identical except that one is a foo and the other is a bar.  In that case I want to keep the foos and discard the bars.

My filter makes two passes over the list.  On the first pass, when a **foo** is encountered I push a string--composed of "**bar**" plus an id value--to a blacklist array.  Then on the second pass I generate the key again and filter out any items that are in the blacklist.

```
var myFilter = function (items) {
    var blacklist = [];

    _.each(items, function (x) {
        if (x.state === 'foo') {
            blacklist.push(['bar', x.id].join(''));
        }
    });

    return _.filter(items, function (x) {
        var key = [x.state, x.id].join('');

        return !_.contains(blacklist, key);
    });
};
```

This method seems pretty ugly and inefficient to me.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and output and a jsfiddle?

Comment: Unless there are some certain invariants on your data structure (like, it being sorted), you won't be able to do much better - two passes is quite fine.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose you are right. I could pre-populate the blacklist server-side, but at that point I might as well do the filtering there too--it's just shifting the same work from one place to another. My responses are fairly small, so this filter isn't a terrible bottleneck. I was just hoping to learn some optimization trickery.

Answer (score 0):

```
_.each(items, function (x) {
    if (x.state === 'foo') {
        var key = ['bar', x.id].join('');
        if ( key in items ) {
            delete items[key];
        }
    }       
});
```

something like this should be close, may need to be fixed a bit but its a single pass

Comment: Thanks, the only problem with this is that `key` doesn't exist in items, so the first pass in myFilter is required in order to generate it.

Comment: yeah i miss read your question sorry about that, seems that two loops may be your only option

Answer (score 0):

Seems that [reject()](https://lodash.com/docs#reject) does everything you need here in a single pass:

```
var coll = [
    { state: 'bar'},
    { state: 'foo' },
    { state: 'bar' },
    { state: 'foo'}
];

_.reject(coll, { state: 'foo' });
// → [ { state: 'bar' }, { state: 'bar' } ]
```